# Gradle repositories as project field

Tags: groovy, gradle

In gradle, I can specify my repositories with custom layout patterns as

```
repositories {
  ivy {
    url "http://repo.mycompany.com/repo"
    layout "pattern", {
        artifact "3rd-party-artifacts/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
        artifact "company-artifacts/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
        ivy "ivy-files/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml"
    }
  }
}
```

Thats fine, but if I also want to use the `uploadArchives` and `buildscript` closures, I also need to specify the repositories. My idea was to break out the repositories as a field.

```
@Field def myRepos = {
  ivy {
    url "http://repo.mycompany.com/repo"
    layout "pattern", {
        artifact "3rd-party-artifacts/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
        artifact "company-artifacts/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
        ivy "ivy-files/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml"
    }
  }
}
```

This works for

```
repositories myRepos
```

but for

```
buildscript {
  repositories myRepos
}
```

and

```
uploadArchives {
  repositories myRepos
}
```

this gives

```
No such property: myRepos for class: 'org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler'
```

My gradle version is 1.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `@Field`, you can just do `def myRepos = ...`. The `buildscript` block is very special, and if you want to share between that and the rest of the build script, you'll have to do `ext.myRepos = ...` inside `buildscript`, and refer to it using `buildscript.myRepos` from the outside.

Comment: This works! Is it possible to extract this lot into a separate, shared build.gradle file (using "apply from")? I tried it but the `buildscript` method does not appear to be called when in an external script, is this also to do with `buildscript` being special?

Comment: Yes. `buildscript` cannot be moved into a separate, shared build script. Perhaps its contents can, but that gets complicated, and I'd try to avoid it. Starting with 2.1 or 2.2, there will be a new `plugins {}` block, which will gradually replace `buildscript` and may work better in that regard.