# Share Gradle "repositories" with "buildscript.repositories"

Tags: gradle

I want the same `repositories` that I specify in the `buildscript.repositories` block to the be the same repositories for the dependencies `repositories` block. Please see my example:

### Normal `buidldscript`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2"
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

How can I do something like the following?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2"
    }
}

repositories = buildscript.repositories
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25240256/gradle-repositories-as-project-field), you simply declare it in a variable first:

```
buildscript {
    ext.myRepos = {
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }

    repositories myRepos

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2"
    }
}

repositories myRepos
```

Ideally, I would like to use the `plugins { }` block but the Android gradle plugin is not on plugins.gradle.org.

or

```
buildscript {
    configure([buildscript.repositories, project.repositories]) {
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2"
    }
}
```